# Topology of the general linear group

Tags: general-topology

Let $GL_{n}(R)$ be all the general linear matices with entries real value.We think these matrices as subspace of $n^{2}$ dimension Euclidean space.
Show that I and -I lie in different path component when $n$ is odd.And I and -I lie in the same component if $n$ is even.

I can show that the determinant function is continuous from $GL_{n}(R)$ to $R-\left\{0\right\}$.If n is odd,$det(I)$ and $det (-I)$ equal 1 and -1.If n is even,$det(I)$ and $det(-I)$ will be 1.Then I don't know how to approach the desired result.Could someone help me a little bit?

Comment: First, can you do the case $n=2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $n$ is odd, The image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected, this implies that $-I$ and $I$ are not in the same connected component, otherwise, $det(I)$ and $det(-I)$ whould have been in the same connected component of $R-\{0\}$. But $det(I)\in \{x,:x>0\}$ and $det(-I)\in \{x:x<0\}$.

If $n$ is even, $n=2p$, you have a basis $(e_i,e_{2i}), i=1,...,p$ consider the linear map $f_t$ whose restriction to $Vect(e_i,e_{2i})$ preserves $Vect(e_i,e_{2i})$ and its matrix in $(e_i,e_{2i})$ is

$\pmatrix{cos(\pi t) & -sin(\pi t)\cr sin(\pi t) & cos(\pi t)}$. The matrix of $f_t,t\in [0,1]$ is a path between $I$ and $-I$.

Comment: who downvote here and why?

Comment: I think because some people confuse up and down.